# Module Not Found in Xcode 10.1 when importing a child project inside the parent project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I got a project from a programmer, built 5 years ago. When I built it, it is showing that the Module is not found. I added two paths to the framework search path and it did not work. I wonder if someone could help me?

[image: Framework search path]
[image: Module not Found]

Answer (score 0):

Check setting for the framework target: "Define Module" — should be Yes, "Product Module Name" — should be same name as you need

[image]

Also add a module framework into your application target on General tab.